# Find and Replace a string in more than one text file in PHP

Tags: php

i found this code:

```
<?php
$path_to_file = 'c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\File.txt';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("Paul",",HHH",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
?>
```

It's working very well if it's only one file but how to do if i want to Find and Replace in all *.txt file of my folder?

THank you

Comment: Can you use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) or it's required to be done with php?

Comment: `foreach(glob('/path/to/*.txt') as $filePath) { your code above }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the files inside a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add wildcard names to directory search in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774127/how-to-add-wildcard-names-to-directory-search-in-php)

Comment: if you are on windows you can just open a command prompt, cd to that folder and do `REN * *.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useful [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), internal PHP function

```
$files_in_your_folder = glob('c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\*');
```

So for your specific case:

```
<?php
foreach(glob('c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\*') as $path_to_file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace("Paul",",HHH",$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$path_to_file =glob( 'c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\*');
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("Paul",",HHH",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
?>

Comment: Thank you Genesis it's working well it was my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 3):

What about this?
It should take care of running your replace on all .txt-files, regardless of how many sub-folders you got in your path folder.

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/textfiles/'); // Path to your textfiles 
$fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($fileList as $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && stripos($item->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) {
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
        $file_contents = str_replace("Paul",",HHH",$file_contents);
        file_put_contents($item->getPathName(),$file_contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: i Have an error on line2
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' 



    <?php
    $path = realpath(c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\); // Path to your textfiles

Comment: Well, you would want to wrap your path with quotes, ie. `<?php $path = realpath('c:\wamp\www\FindReplace');`

Comment: Cool, thanks, this has really helped me a lot to change and saved too much of work and time, Great stuff! Though I have one more doubt, I have 3 to 4 lines to be replace one shot, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/your/project -name '*.txt' -exec php yourScript.php {} \;
```

Then modify your script to use command line argument `$argv[1]` as the file path.